# NullPointerException when parsing XML data with geocoding API in Processing

Tags: java, xml, nullpointerexception, processing, geocoding

I am using Processing and I am loading data from a csv table, whose one column includes country names. For each country I am trying to use the Google Geocoding API to get the respective latitude and longitude values, however I am getting a NullPointerException error. Here is my code:

```
import processing.xml.*;

Bubble[] bubbles;
Table table;

void setup() {
  size(displayWidth, displayHeight);
  loadData();
}  

void draw() {
  background(255);
  for (int i = 0; i < bubbles.length ; i++) {
    bubbles[i].display();
    bubbles[i].rollover(mouseX, mouseY);    
   }
}

void loadData() {
 table = loadTable("terroristAttacks.csv", "header");

 bubbles = new Bubble[table.getRowCount()]; 

 for (int i = 0; i < table.getRowCount(); i++) {
   TableRow row = table.getRow(i);
   float estimate = row.getFloat("Estimate");
   float diameter = estimate*0.17;
   String name = row.getString("Name");
   String country = row.getString("Country");
   int year = row.getInt("Date");

   API_KEY = "MY_API";
   String location = country;
   String url = 
  "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?address=" +
  location + "&key=" + API_KEY;
   XML root = loadXML(url);
   XML lat = root.getChild("result/geometry/location/lat");
   XML lng = root.getChild("result/geometry/location/lng");

   float latitude = lat.getFloatContent();    
   float longitude = lng.getFloatContent();

   float x = random(diameter/2, width-diameter/2); 
   float y = random(diameter/2, height-diameter/2);

   println();
   println(estimate + " estimate: row " + i + " with name " + name + 
   ". x = " + x + ", y = " + y + ", diameter = " + diameter + ", date: " +
   year + ", country: " + location);
   println(url);        

   bubbles[i] = new Bubble(x, y, diameter, name, year);
 }

}

boolean sketchFullScreen() { // full screen
  return true;
 }
```

And the error appears at the line:

```
float latitude = lat.getFloatContent();
```

FYI, when commenting the above line and the one after (float longitude) I don't get an error message and I receive every URL (for each country) printed in my console.

Could you help?
Thanks, Ilias

Here an XML response for Pakistan:

```
<GeocodeResponse>
 <status>OK</status>
 <result>
  <type>country</type>
  <type>political</type>
  <formatted_address>Pakistan</formatted_address>
  <address_component>
   <long_name>Pakistan</long_name>
   <short_name>PK</short_name>
   <type>country</type>
   <type>political</type>
  </address_component>
  <geometry>
   <location>
    <lat>30.3753210</lat>
    <lng>69.3451160</lng>
   </location>
   <location_type>APPROXIMATE</location_type>
   <viewport>
    <southwest>
     <lat>23.6946945</lat>
     <lng>60.8729720</lng>
    </southwest>
    <northeast>
     <lat>37.0841070</lat>
     <lng>77.8316195</lng>
    </northeast>
   </viewport>
   <bounds>
    <southwest>
     <lat>23.6946945</lat>
     <lng>60.8729720</lng>
    </southwest>
    <northeast>
     <lat>37.0841070</lat>
     <lng>77.8316195</lng>
    </northeast>
   </bounds>
  </geometry>
  <place_id>ChIJH3X9-NJS2zgRXJIU5veht0Y</place_id>
 </result>
</GeocodeResponse>
```

Comment: Can you give us an example of what url you're loading from? Apparently your `lat` variable is null, so you have to figure out why. Are you sure it's in the xml?

Comment: Please post the xml that gives you the error as well.

Comment: Just posted an XML example

Comment: What processing version are you using?

Comment: It's Processing 2.2.1

Comment: I have the same version but your example tells me to remove the `import processing.xml.*;` line because it's not used anymore... If I do that and put the xml in a file then it works just fine...

Comment: I found the solution. Since I am parsing xml data with the Google Geocoding API I do need to import the xml library - this was not the problem. The problem was that my API requests exceeded the permitted request quota / second, therefore I had to apply some delay() in order to receive all needed responses. Thanks very much for your help.